# Re-order rows in a partition with window function? - BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Im trying to re-order some rows within a partition and switch the values from left to right.
Let me explain. I receive data for "vehicles" in a factory. All these vehicles are moved in groups or "trains". Sometimes the vehicles have the wrong orientation which is recorded as a "2" in the data (see field vehicle_orientation). Vehicles have an ID but not always. Vehicles may have 2-6 axles in total. In my example there are only vehicles with 4 axles (vehicle_axles_count).

My problem:

For the vehicles with orientation = 2, that is vehicles with a "wrong" orientation, I need re-order the axles and switch values from left to right and right to left. So, in my example, there's a vehicle "4567400010333" with 4 axles and I need to take the rows and re-order them so the axle_number_vehicle come in the "correct" order. Also, left values should be switched to right, and right to left.

I have been playing around with window-functions: nth_value but cant do it right.

Any Ideas?

```
message_id  send_time_stamp_time    vehicle_tag_id  vehicle_axle_count  vehicle_orientation axle_number_train   axle_number_vehicle left_mean_value right_mean_value
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     4567400010333  4                      2                      1                 4                     91.0             90.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     4567400010333  4                      2                      2                 3                     98.0             89.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     4567400010333  4                      2                      3                 2                     89.0             88.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     4567400010333  4                      2                      4                 1                     87.0             93.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     1234400019876  4                      1                      5                 1                     78.0             100.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     1234400019876  4                      1                      6                 2                     92.0             88.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     1234400019876  4                      1                      7                 3                     102.0           80.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     1234400019876  4                      1                      8                 4                     84.0             104.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44                      4                    0                      9                 1                     65.0             88.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44                      4                    0                      10                2                   66.0               82.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44                      4                    0                      11                3                   65.0               80.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44                      4                    0                      12                4                   66.0               84.0
```

Expected output where order of vehicle 4567400010333 is in another order:

```
message_id  send_time_stamp_time    vehicle_tag_id  vehicle_axle_count  vehicle_orientation axle_number_train   axle_number_vehicle left_mean_value right_mean_value
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     4567400010333  4                      2                      1                 1                     87.0             93.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     4567400010333  4                      2                      2                 2                     89.0             88.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     4567400010333  4                      2                      3                 3                     98.0             89.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     4567400010333  4                      2                      4                 4                     91.0             90.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     1234400019876  4                      1                      5                 1                     78.0             100.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     1234400019876  4                      1                      6                 2                     92.0             88.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     1234400019876  4                      1                      7                 3                     102.0           80.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44     1234400019876  4                      1                      8                 4                     84.0             104.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44                        4                    0                      9                 1                     65.0             88.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44                        4                    0                      10                2                   66.0               82.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44                        4                    0                      11                3                   65.0               80.0
478542900    2020-02-04 14:36:44                        4                    0                      12                4                   66.0               84.0
```

Comment: Could you provide the expected output table so that it will help to understand and provide the query for your expected table.

Comment: Hi, Yes. Provided expected output. Now you see that the order of the first vehicle is changed. You see that in the values but also axle_number_train and axle_number_vehicle. @SandeepMohanty